# separate string into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a fields in a mysql table that stores the ProjectTeam values as (val1,val2)
I would like to get each value in ProjectTeam into the HTML and each one must link to a separated link.
how can i echo each array element. The code below display correctly, but all values are identified as one link. Any help is appreciated.

```
function list_account_projects($new_projectAccount){
    $this->projectAccountName = $new_projectAccount;
    $listQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * from projects 
           WHERE projectAccount = '$this->projectAccountName'");

    while  ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($listQuery)){
        $this->projectName = $rows['projectName'];
        $this->projectType = $rows['projectType'];
        $this->projectTeam = $rows['projectTeam'];
        $this->projectOwner= $rows['projectOwner'];
        $this->projectStartDate = $rows['projectStartDate'];

        //Convert date backwards 
        $re_projectStartDate = date('m-d-y', strtotime($this->projectStartDate));

     //split ProjectTeam ',' - Optional
     $splitUsers = explode( ',', $this->projectTeam );
       foreach( $splitUsers as $user ) {
                  $user = trim( $user );
            }


        echo "
             <div class=\"list-group\">
             <a class=\"list-group-item active\" href=\"#\">$this->projectName <p class=\"pull-right\">Due Date: $re_projectStartDate</p></a>
              <a class=\"list-group-item \" > 
                     Project Name: $this->projectName</br>
                     Project Type:  $this->projectType</br>
                     Project Owner: $this->projectOwner</br>
                   Project Team: <a href=\"$user\">$user</a></a>
                         </div>
                     ";

    }
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Comment: you cannot use nested a tags

Answer (score 0):

You can take values in while like that 
echo should like this to echo your variables

```
echo "<div class=\"list-group\">".$example."</div>";

while  ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($listQuery)){
        $projectName = $rows['projectName'];
        $projectType = $rows['projectType'];
        $projectTeam = $rows['projectTeam'];
        $projectOwner= $rows['projectOwner'];
        $projectStartDate = $rows['projectStartDate'];
```

see

then you can print them like that

```
 echo "
             <div class=\"list-group\">
             <a class=\"list-group-item active\" href=\"#\">".$projectName ."<p class=\"pull-right\">Due Date:". $re_projectStartDate."</p></a>
              <a class=\"list-group-item \" > 
                     Project Name:". $projectName."</br>
                     Project Type:".  $projectType."</br>
                     Project Owner:". $projectOwner."</br>
                   Project Team: <a href='".$projectTeam."'>".$projectTeam."</a></a>
                         </div>
                     ";
```

Comment: Thanks, But the values are still considered one link.

Comment: try echo $projectOwner something?

Comment: By the way what you mean by values are still considered one link

Comment: The code dispalys all users correctly, but the <a href> applies to all of them at one, I wanted to have each user with his/ her <a href link> so in a sense, i wanted to do a forwach inside an echo statement - which i know is not supported.

Comment: not necessary you can take like this suppose three users A B C you can make link then href="YOUR LINK.php?user = ".$user." now what is user here from above variables i dun know but Would like to help if u edit your post and add more and if this answer helped u u can accept answer

Comment: M.Chaudhry,I edited the post. My issue is that each project has multiple team members. I want to be able to view each team member in the lat echo statement and have each member clickble link to the member profile.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested a tags, Please try this code,

`echo "
             <div class=\"list-group\">
             <a class=\"list-group-item active\" href=\"#\">$this->projectName <p class=\"pull-right\">Due Date: $re_projectStartDate</p></a>
              <div class=\"list-group-item \" > 
                     Project Name: $this->projectName</br>
                     Project Type:  $this->projectType</br>
                     Project Owner: $this->projectOwner</br>
                   Project Team: <a href=\"$this->projectTeam\">$this->projectTeam</a></div>
                         </div>
                     ";`